# MySql - How to assign different aliases to a single select column, determined by a case statement

Tags: mysql, select, case, prepared-statement, alias

I have this following working code (MySql 8.0):

```
    select user_id as "user",
        (case when userBad then CodeRed 
        else CodeBlue
        end)
    From colours
```

I want to assign an alias Red for CodeRed column, and Blue for CodeBlue column.  I know I can't give an alias within the case statement.  So what would be the correct syntax to assigning a condition alias?  I thought perhaps I declare a string variable to hold the value of the alias and then append the variable to the case statement:

```
declare alias varchar(4);
if userBad then set alias = "Red"
else set alias = "Blue";
select user_id as "user",
       (case when userBad then CodeRed 
       else CodeBlue
       end) as alias
From colours;
```

But as you probably expected, I end up with a column called alias!  So is there a way to assign conditional aliases based on case select?  Thanks

UPDATE:  Slava has provided a great solution using a prepared statement to concatinate the alias variable.  My Full code:  I now currently get an error 1054: Unknown column userBad in 'field list' but I am confident Slava has put me on the right track.

```
PROCEDURE `Test`(userBad bool)
BEGIN
    declare alias varchar(4);    

    drop temporary table if exists colours;
    create temporary table colours (user_id int, codeRed int, codeBlue int);
    

    if userBad then set alias = "Red";
    else set alias = "Blue";
    end if;
    
    SET @sql = CONCAT('select user_id as "user",
           (case when userBad = true then codeRed 
           else codeBlue
           end) as ', alias, ' from colours');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

FINAL UPDATE: I have solved the "1054: Unknown column userBad in 'field list'" error.  I posted the full working solution below.  My thanks to Slava in putting me on the right track of using prepared statements.

Comment: Each column in the resultset has a name/alias. What name/alias do you want for this column returned by CASE. You know that it is only 1 column, right?

Comment: Hi forpas, I know that the case will only give one column  but I like to know how to give a different alias depending on the resulting column of the case statement.  So if Case results in CodeRed column then I want to give it an alias "Red".  If it results in a CodeBlue column, then want to give it an alias "Blue".  That is my whole question.  Sorry if it wasn't clear in the main post.  Thanks

Comment: It can be done by Stored Procedure. Within stored procedure you can build query by condition and return its result

Comment: A query may return more than 1 rows. Some of the rows may contain CodeRed and others CodeBlue in that column. So what name/alias do you want for that column?

Comment: Hi Slava, the code is in a Stored Procedure.

Comment: hi forpas, codeRed and CodeBlue are column names defined in the colours table. The case statement determines which of those columns is in the select by the boolean value of userBad.  If codeRed is the result of the case statement, then I want the alias of the column to be "Red".  If codeBlue is the result, then I want the alias of the column to be "Blue".  Hope that clarifies my intended code further. Thanks

Comment: To expand what @forpas said:  Each column in the resultset has only 1 name/alias.

Comment: You cannot set the alias dynamically within the same sql statement. You can use prepared statement to dynamically create the sql statement. However, it may be better, if you used a field value as opposed to alias to indicate certain status

Comment: or you can define 2 columns, like `select user_id as "user", case when userBad then CodeRed end as Red, case when not userBad then CodeBlue end as Blue from colours;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank Slava for putting me on the right track with using prepared statements.  It was a close solution that didn't quite work and other solutions were not quite the required results.

A prepared statement was the solution but there was an issue in that the variable *userBad* was rejected. What I realise is we can't have variables inside the prepared statement but we can have a placeholder value, represented by *?* then execute the statement USING *userBad*. However, that still gives errors because the USING clause of executing a prepared statement requires a user/session variable, not a local variable.  Therefore need to assign local variable *userBad* to a session variable @uB.  The full working solution is as follows:

```
PROCEDURE `Test`(userBad int)
BEGIN
    declare alias varchar(4);


    drop temporary table if exists colours;
    create temporary table colours (user_id int, codeRed int, codeBlue int);
    

    if userBad then set alias = "Red";
    else set alias = "Blue";
    end if;

    set @uB = userBad;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('select user_id as "user",
           (case when ? then codeRed 
           else codeBlue
           end) as ', alias, ' from colours');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt using @uB;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
END
```

One more thing to add, for those of you looking for such a solution, if you have more than one session variable, you need to list those variables out in the sequence used in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

In stored procedure you can do something like:

```
declare alias varchar(4);
if userBad then alias = "Red"
else alias = "Blue";

SET @sql = CONCAT('select user_id as ', alias, ' from colours');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The above code only illustrate the idea of dynamic query. Query in your case can be different.

Below full stored procedure code.

```
PROCEDURE `Test`(userBad bool)
BEGIN
    declare alias varchar(4);    

    drop temporary table if exists colours;
    create temporary table colours (user_id int, codeRed int, codeBlue int);
    

    if userBad then 
        set alias = "Red";
    else 
        set alias = "Blue";
    end if;
    
    SET @sql = CONCAT(
        'select user_id as "user", code', alias, ' as ', alias, ' from colours'
    );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Another code:

```
PROCEDURE `Test`(userBad bool)
    BEGIN
    
        drop temporary table if exists colours;
        create temporary table colours (user_id int, codeRed int, codeBlue int);
        
        if userBad then 
            SET @sql = 'select user_id as "user", codeRed as Red from colours';
        else 
            SET @sql = 'select user_id as "user", codeBlue as Blue from colours';
        end if;
    
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END;
```

Comment: Ah, you are using a prepared statement, clever.  I see that will work.  My code is indeed in a stored procedure.  I'll try this out now and update.  Many thanks for your quick and clever solution.

Comment: Ok @TheyCallMeTJ, tell me know how it helpful

Comment: Hi Slava, would you mind take a quick look at the full Procedure code I updated in the main post, I am confident your solution puts me on track but I get a curious error 1054: Unknown column userBad in 'field list'.  I'm troubleshooting that right now, it's probably something silly

Comment: Its strange, isolating the select statement without the alias works fine but as a prepared statement, I get that 1054: Unknown Column error.  Update - sorry ignore this I didnt notice your last reply.  Will try your new code

Comment: sorry ignore my last, I didnt notice your last reply.  Will try your new code

Comment: Ok your first solution is based on the coincidence of name and alias sharing same substring of characters but can't be used generally if alias and name are alike. Your alternative solution is repeating whole query for each case result.  My reality is that I have a long query with more case options but for simplicity of the question, I projected a simplified test scenario. So the second solution is not favourable for long queries. I liked your very first solution which you have overwritten even though it didn't quite work due to error 1054 Unknown Column,  If I can troubleshoot that error..!